# Error opening some xlsx file in UIWebview

Tags: ios, exception, uiwebview

i can successfully open a local copy of xlsx file in UIWebview

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[detailItem valueForKey:@"path"]]];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
[self.documentWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL]];
```

but for some files i am getting Exception in console logs.I dont know where these exception are coming from & how to trap that

```
<Warning>: exception: Could not find the end of central directory record
<Warning>: EXCEPTION SFUZipEndOfCentralDirectoryError: Could not find the end of central directory record
```

This file only start loading

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType <br>
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

are called
& neither of below delegates are called

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView <br>
```

When i try to load second file in some webview  which loads file & i get **didFailLoadWithError** called for previous xlsx
below are console logs

```
-----====UIWebview shouldStartLoadWithRequest: /var/mobile/Applications/08653237-F656-42F7-B405-1F89C208A866/Documents/12 So1 what is new in Excel 2007.xlsx =======-------
webViewDidStartLoad 
exception: Could not find the end of central directory record 
EXCEPTION SFUZipEndOfCentralDirectoryError: Could not find the end of central directory record
```

Logs for second file

```
webView didFailLoadWithError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x5655c30 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/mobile/Applications/08653237-F656-42F7-B405-1F89C208A866/Documents/12%20So1%20what%20is%20new%20in%20Excel%202007.xlsx, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/mobile/Applications/08653237-F656-42F7-B405-1F89C208A866/Documents/12%20So1%20what%20is%20new%20in%20Excel%202007.xlsx}
webViewDidStartLoad

Detail View finished /var/mobile/Applications/08653237-F656-42F7-B405-1F89C208A866/Documents/a.txt :
```

Is this due to UIWebview caching ? How can i trap UIWebview exceptions?

Comment: I am having the same issue, and I think it is related to the type of xls format (in my case, xml based xls)...
Did you find any workaround?

Comment: I am facing this issue while opening the password protected .xlsx/.docx

Answer (score 0):

It may be because your meta data of the file is corrupted. I was having the same issue, but found that the url response was in fact an html page error, which was returned as data from IIS server. I wrote this directly to file. I was not getting any error in &error variable, though. It was actually a server error!